# Android Webview, Java Forms storing data from fields and putting them back on load

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I've looked through dozens of posts and im not quit find anything that works for me. What ive got is an Android and IOS app that loads a webview in the webview is a google form. what I need to do is when the user fills out the form and hits submit I need to capture specific fields into variables then on the next load put the contents of the variables back so they do not have to type in fields like their names every time.

Currently focusing on the Android part ive got this code:

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("website.com");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    String name = "example";
    String email = "example";
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
            "document.getElementsByjsname('W85ice').value = '"+email +"';" +
            "document.getElementsBylabel('Your Name').value = '"+name+"';" +
            "var frms = document.getElementsByName('submit');" +
            "frms[0].submit(); };");
```

The code from the form is

```
<div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputEl freebirdFormviewerViewItemsTextShortText freebirdFormviewerViewItemsTextEmail freebirdThemedInput" jscontroller="pxq3x" jsaction="clickonly:KjsqPd; focus:Jt1EX; blur:fpfTEe; input:Lg5SV;" jsshadow="" jsname="W85ice"><div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputMainContent exportContent"><div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputContentArea exportContentArea"><div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInputArea"><input type="email" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Work Email Address" aria-describedby="i.desc.1470811872 i.err.1470811872" name="entry.2089120054" value="" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value=""><div jsname="LwH6nd" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel">Your answer</div></div><div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputUnderline exportUnderline"></div><div jsname="XmnwAc" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputFocusUnderline exportFocusUnderline animationInitialized" style="transform-origin: 82px center 0px;"></div></div></div><div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputCounterErrorHolder"><div jsname="ty6ygf" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputHint exportHint"></div></div></div>
```

I get no errors, but im also getting no results ive tried pulling diffrent id's but nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated. this is a side project for my job.